# DTD syntax - Is it possible to specify an element that can only contain attributes?

Tags: xml, dtd

Using DTD syntax, can one specify an element that contains only attributes, and no possible child node? Meaning no child elements or no child text.

I want a dtd to restrict an element as follows:

```
<element att1="CDATA" att2="CDATA"/>
```

I've tried this, but %element.content; won't validate:

```
<!ENTITY % element.content "">
<!ENTITY % element.attributes
            "att1
                    CDATA 
                            #REQUIRED
             att2
                    CDATA 
                            #REQUIRED">
<!ATTLIST element     %element.attributes;>
<!ELEMENT element     %element.content;>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer after posting:

```
<!ENTITY % element.content "EMPTY">
```

Duh.